# Bootstrap The toggle button in the navbar shift the content to the left

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with the navbar on my website. In the mobile version, the toggle button in the navbar shifts the website to the left, and the content is not centered.

But, in my navigator, in responsive mode, the website is centered and the toggle button doesn’t shift the website to the left.

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>*******************</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicon-96x96.png">

    <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">*****</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#qsj">Qui-suis-je</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#competences">Compétences</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#real">Réalisations</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="box-present">
      <div class="box-present-title">
        <h1>****************</h1>
        <h2>Développeur Web PHP</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="box-present-img-dev">
        <div class="box-img-perso">
          <img src="vf.jpg" class="img-perso" alt=" " />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-website" data-bs-offset="0" tabindex="0">

    /* The rest of the main */

  </main>

  <footer>
      ...  /* The rest of the footer */
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #303030;
}

 .nav-link {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    text-align: center;;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #303030;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(48,48,48, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.box-present {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 15rem;
}

.box-present-title {
    background-color: #54F98D;
    width: 600px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box-present-img-dev {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #FF866A;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
}

.box-title-site {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

.box-present-title > h1 {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 12rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-img-perso {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.box-present-title > h2 {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 12rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-img-perso > .img-perso {
    height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    border: 15px solid #303030;
    border-radius: 50% 20% / 10% 40%;
}

/* The rest of the css */
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Max Muster</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicon-96x96.png">

        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="fixed-top">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Max Muster</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#qsj">Qui-suis-je</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#competences">Compétences</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#real">Réalisations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="box-present">
            <div class="box-present-title">
            <h1>Max Muster</h1>
            <h2>Développeur Web PHP</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-present-img-dev">
            <div class="box-img-perso">
                <img src="vf.jpg" class="img-perso" alt=" " />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-website" data-bs-offset="0" tabindex="0">


        <!-- The rest of the main -->


    </main>

        <footer>
            ...  /*the rest of the footer*/
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #303030;
}

 .nav-link {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    text-align: center;;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #00cc99;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10rem;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #00cc99;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 204, 153, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  main {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you change? And why? E.g., the syntax highlighter doesn't like it near ".navbar-toggler-icon": the string "`...;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(48,48,48, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E`" was changed to "`...,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 204, 153, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e`". Why?

Comment: Though it may very well be the syntax highlighter fault (the weird syntax highlighting, that is).

Comment: An explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74893014/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).  Thanks in advance.